# Is it possible to set d option for Code Sniffer in PHPStorm

Tags: php, refactoring, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, code-inspection

I want to run code inspector in PHPStorm with Code Sniffer package. But Code Sniffer generates lot of useless messages for example "Default timezone is required since PHP 5.4". For manual usage of Code Sniffer I can use d option to set up PHP settings. E.g

```
phpcs -d date.timezone=Europe/Amsterdam
```

Is it possible to set up this option for PHPStorm?

Comment: Why don't you want to set the timezone globally in `php.ini`?

Comment: BTW in Netbeans, there is "Full path of Code Sniffer script" field in Options dialog, so I guess you can set parameters in that field. PHPStorm should have something similar. How did you configured, where PHPStorm looks for Code Sniffer? Or do you have "phpcs" script in the path?

Comment: I set timezone in php.ini, and timezone have right value in phpinfo(). But usage phpcs from command line or from PHPStorm shows that timezone haven't set.

Comment: Sure, CLI PHP has its own php.ini, so set it there. Use `php -i` to find out, where it's located. Or better `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` or `php --ini`.

Comment: Please consider marking of any answer that helped to solve your issue as an "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and No** (most likely No)

**Yes** -- you can configure `-d` params at PHP Interpreter level.

`Settings | PHP` -- click on `...` button to get to list of PHP interpreters.

**P.S.**
This will affect all scripts/tools executed using this particular PHP Interpreter from within IDE.

---

**No** -- I strongly believe that PHPCS does not use that PHP Interpreter -- because when you configuring `phpcs`, you are providing full path to executable file 1) which will be executed using system default PHP and 2) you cannot pass any custom options when providing it (only path to the file)

**Therefore** -- better configure default time zone in actual php.ini

Comment: Yep, I also vote for setting system-wide timezone in `php.ini`. You always get warning, if it's not set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Phpcs does not use that PHP Interpreter indeed. But I found another way to solve the problem - I have added timezone option to phpcs.bat - file

Comment: Why do you want to solve it for each particular script and not for all PHP executions? If you add for example PHPMD, phpUnit or another tool, you'll have to set it again and again.

Comment: You are right, it's much more convenient to set this option globally.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to set timezone system-wide in `php.ini`. See [PHP datetime configuration documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone). To find out where an active `php.ini` is located, you can use function `phpinfo()`. CLI PHP uses its own `php.ini`. To find out, where it's located you can use for example:

`php -i`

`php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`

`php --ini`

Find "timezone", uncomment and set it according your needs. You can find a [list of supported time zones in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

If you don't have the timezone set, you always get a warning, therefore it's better to set it system-wide. You don't have to care about each script execution then.